# awk multiline problem

Tags: bash, awk

Have been trying to write an awk script which processes a log file, but am struggling.

I have a file which has lines which look like this:

```
[2011-07-29 04:44:37.100 INFO] AU/SUB1/Server:WebHits : Hits[ABC]=0; Hits[DEF]=876; Hits[THY]=0; Hits[SG]=891; Hits[XFRR]=1386
[2011-07-29 04:44:37.599 INFO] AU/SUB2/Server:WebHits : Hits[XARR]=0; Hits[XXX]=0; Hits[ABS]=0; Hits[SM]=0
[2011-07-29 04:44:37.699 INFO] AU/MAIN/Server:Main : Hits=254
[2011-07-29 04:44:38.100 INFO] AU/SUB1/Server:WebHits : Hits[ABC]=0; Hits[DEF]=1134; Hits[THY]=0; Hits[SG]=1153; Hits[XFRR]=426
[2011-07-29 04:44:38.599 INFO] AU/SUB2/Server:WebHits : Hits[XARR]=0; Hits[XXX]=0; Hits[ABS]=0; Hits[SM]=22
[2011-07-29 04:44:38.699 INFO] AU/MAIN/Server:Main : Hits=436
```

As you can see there are three lines per second (there will always be three lines per second).  I would like to combine these lines (one line per second), so that a summary would look like this, so one line of summary correlators to three lines from the input log file:

```
[2011-07-29 04:44:37 INFO] MainHits=254,ABC=0,DEF=876,THY=0,SG=891,XFRR=1386,XARR=0,XXX=0,ABS=0,SM=0
[2011-07-29 04:44:38 INFO] MainHits=436,ABC=0,DEF=1134,THY=0,SG=1153,XFRR=426,XARR=0,XXX=0,ABS=0,SM=22
```

Please note the venue names e.g. "ABC,DEF,THY,SG etc" can change dynamically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And there will **always** be 3 records per sec? Or can that sometimes slip to 1 or 2, or maybe 4,5? Can you define it as any time the second value changes, you want a record output of the activity for all current tags? (as of that second). Good luck!

Comment: Hi shelter.  Have updated the question.  Yes there will always be 3 per second.  And I would like to see one summary line per second whether data has updated or not.

Comment: you wrote 'summary line per second whether data has updated or not.' That's a whole separate problem.  If you're loading this data into a database, it would be much easier to generate your empty records there. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution relies heavily on the input format you've posted:

```
awk '/Main :/ {
  sub(/\.[0-9]*/, x, $2)
  print $1, $2, $3, "Main" $NF, r
  r = x; next
  }
{
  gsub(/Hits\[/, x)
  gsub(/[];]/, x)
  for (i = 5; ++i <= NF;)
    r = r ? r "," $i : $i
  }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

A cryptic solution using sed:

```
sed -e 'N;N;s/\n\[.\{28\}\]/;/g;s/\.... INFO/ INFO/;s!AU/SUB1/Server:WebHits : !!;s!AU/SUB2/Server:WebHits : !!;s!AU/MAIN/Server:Main : !!;s/ INFO\] \(.*\) Hits=\(.*\)/ INFO\] MainHits=\2 \1/;s/ Hits\[\([^]]*\)\]=\([^;]*\);/,\1=\2/g' infile
```

This deserves some explanations, so bellow is a commented script file version . It must be run with `'sed -f script infile'`

```
# Read 2 more lines, so we will have 3 lines are in the pattern space.
N
N
# Change the timestamps of the 2 extra lines by a ;.
s/\n\[.\{28\}\]/;/g
# Remove the milliseconds of the remaining timestamp, and the extra data of each line.
s/\.... INFO/ INFO/
s!AU/SUB1/Server:WebHits : !!
s!AU/SUB2/Server:WebHits : !!
s!AU/MAIN/Server:Main : !!
# Generate the MainHits data.
s/ INFO\] \(.*\) Hits=\(.*\)/ INFO\] MainHits=\2 \1/
# Format the Hits data.
s/ Hits\[\([^]]*\)\]=\([^;]*\);/,\1=\2/g
```